# spring-jdbc upgrade issue causing performance issues

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I ran many tests on old(any version <=3.1.2 using 3.0.5 and new spring-jdbc-.jar(any version >3.1.2 using 4.1.4)  and after testing with log level TRACE & running in DEBUG mode manage to identify the spring-jdbc-.jar code causing bottleneck.

The code in JDBCTemplate.java at line number-755(4.1.4 version) in org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#batchUpdate(java.lang.String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter) is running slow as compared to 3.0.5 release. However both are trying to achieve the same.

```
//below is the piece of code getting executed
    if(rowsAffectedArray < batchSize) {
        pss.setValues(ps, rowsAffectedArray);
        if(ipss == null || !ipss.isBatchExhausted(rowsAffectedArray)) {
            var11.add(Integer.valueOf(ps.executeUpdate()));
            ++rowsAffectedArray;
            continue;
        }
    }
```

This while loop iterates over the list of rows which is less than batch size (which is 50k in our case) sets the values in prepared statement. The difference is significant when the batch size increases.

I searched over the internet and tried to find any difference in spring jdbc code to decipher this but not of much help. Sending this to wider audience to have multiple ideas floating in to find the root cause.

Comment: Have you done any profiling?